# Javascript function with default argument and a multiple-argument

Tags: javascript, optional-parameters

Let's say I have a function declaration like this:

```
function manyParams(a, b=1, ...n) { ... }
```

Now clearly I can call this function in such a way that I can provide `a`, `b`, and then any number of additional arguments under an array `n`.

Example:

```
function manyParams(a, b=1, ...n) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(b));
    console.log(n.length);
}
```

If you call this function with the following arguments `manyParams(1, 1, "John", "Stacy", "Mike", "Bob", "carly");`, you get this output, which makes sense:

```
1
1
5
```

However, what if I want to use the default value in `b`, while still providing many arguments, how do I specify that `"John"` is the start of `n`? I would think I could do something like this: `manyParams(a=1, n="John", "Stacy", "Mike", "Bob", "carly");` but that doesn't work.
Running those arguments gives me the following output:

```
1
"John"
4
```

Comment: Make the first argument as object. `function manyParams({a, b=1}, ...n) { ... }`

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I think that by declaring the function like you did (a, b=1, ...n), you basically said that there is minimum 2 arguments, (a ,b) and possibly many more (...n). So when you call the function, first 2 parameters will always be a and b.

Comment: You're looking for `manyParams(a, undefined, "John", "Stacy", "Mike", "Bob", "carly");`